# C# format string to DateTime

Tags: c#, string, datetime, format

I read a datetime from text file with this format

> Thu Apr 16 09:55:44 2015

How can I format this like 16/04/2015 09:55:44 ?

Answer (score 11):

Do it in two steps. Use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) to parse the original string, then use `ToString()` to output it in the other [desired format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var input = "Thu Apr 16 09:55:44 2015";

var parsed =
    DateTime.ParseExact(input, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var output = parsed.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Better to pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` in `ToString` to keep the output *(delimiter)* culture independent

Comment: I meant in `ToString` like `parsed.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CutureInfo.InvariantCulture);` Without it, it could result in a different date separator, for example if the default culture is `en-IN`, you will get the output as: `16-04-2015 09:55:44`,

Comment: *I edited your answer, I hope you don't mind that.* Yes I said in `ToString` but you passed in `Parsing` *(DateTime.ParseExact)* which should be correct as well. But I was pointing about formatted output.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to convert to DateTime: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165448.aspx

Then you need to convert to String again, using the correctly format, as you can see here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx

---

```
// This example displays the following output to the console: 
//       d: 6/15/2008 
//       D: Sunday, June 15, 2008 
//       f: Sunday, June 15, 2008 9:15 PM 
//       F: Sunday, June 15, 2008 9:15:07 PM 
//       g: 6/15/2008 9:15 PM 
//       G: 6/15/2008 9:15:07 PM 
//       m: June 15 
//       o: 2008-06-15T21:15:07.0000000 
//       R: Sun, 15 Jun 2008 21:15:07 GMT 
//       s: 2008-06-15T21:15:07 
//       t: 9:15 PM 
//       T: 9:15:07 PM 
//       u: 2008-06-15 21:15:07Z 
//       U: Monday, June 16, 2008 4:15:07 AM 
//       y: June, 2008 
//        
//       'h:mm:ss.ff t': 9:15:07.00 P 
//       'd MMM yyyy': 15 Jun 2008 
//       'HH:mm:ss.f': 21:15:07.0 
//       'dd MMM HH:mm:ss': 15 Jun 21:15:07 
//       '\Mon\t\h\: M': Month: 6 
//       'HH:mm:ss.ffffzzz': 21:15:07.0000-07:00
```